# Why my validation is not working in django-rest serializer?

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework, django-validation

Appointment is being registered although I am providing before time in **start** time for appointment.

**models.py**

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(
        choices=APPOINMENT_STATUSES,
        max_length=20,
        default=SCHEDULED,
        help_text="",
    )
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_TYPE, max_length=10, default=MALE)
    email =  models.EmailField()
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, validators=[validate_phone_no])
    start = models.DateTimeField(max_length=50, help_text="Appointment start Date & Time")
    end = models.DateTimeField(max_length=50, help_text="Appointment End Date & Time")
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True) 
    message = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class AppointmentCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = Appointment
        fields = '__all__'
 

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return super().create(validated_data)


    def validate(self, attrs):
        # check appointment start and end time

        if attrs["start"] < timezone.now():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Appointment date cannot be in the past")

        if attrs["start"] >= attrs["end"]:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                f"Appointment end date/time should be after than start/date time."
            )
        return super().validate(attrs)
```

**Description:**

This is my appointment model and serializer for that. Why my validation is not working.

I want, the user wont be able to create appointment if the *start* date and time is before current date and time. ----------------> But Appointment is getting registered, if User is entering today date but before time .

*What's Wrong with this?
and What can be better solution for this problem?*

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error? If so, provide the full traceback. Unexpected result? If so, provide expected and actual results.

Comment: Are you sure about the type of attrs and timezone ? Can you actually compare them ?

Comment: you can see the model.......            and not working means --> I am able to register appointment if i provide start time before current time on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your validation is working correctly. The reason why you don't see it probably is timezone. Let's say you have timezone = "UTC" in settings and now is 18:00 in your local time and 11:00 according to UTC (the difference is 7 hours). If you send "start" in request without timezone indication for example 2022-12-27T17:00 so the server will think that it's 17:00 according to UTC and so 17:00 is later then 11:00.

try to send start date with indication of amounts of hours from utc and see if it works. In my example it would be 2022-12-27T17:00:00+07:00 and so server should convert it to 10:00 in utc (or other timezone you are using in settings) what is earlier then 11:00

Comment: Thanks man! It worked.. In settings: I changed TIME_ZONE = "Asia/Kathmandu".  from UTC.